# Why can't I properly set a volatile registry value?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

A reg key exists in "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LedaSoft\Osmium" but I'm trying to temporarily overwrite it with a volatile key.

```
RegistryKey apikeytest = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\LedaSoft\Osmium", true, (RegistryOptions)0x1);
            Console.WriteLine("Writing key...");
            apikeytest.SetValue("API", "123");
```

In RegEdit, the value never changes from what it was set as before, however the following code returns "123" as expected:

```
string Key = (string)apikey.GetValue("API", "").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(Key);
```

After a reboot, it still returns "123" even though RegEdit shows the original value.

1. Why isn't it showing the volatile change in RegEdit? Is it supposed to?
2. Why is it still returning "123" after a reboot, again with RegEdit showing the original value?

EDIT: After further testing, I can't set ANY value, volatile or not. The program returns with the correct setting, but regedit doesn't show it.

EDIT2: My AV was sandboxing the program.